# Google App Engine PHP error 204

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-app-engine-php

I have been receiving the following 204 error approximately once a week for the past 6 weeks and can't figure out what is causing the error.

> A problem was encountered with the process that handled this request,
>   causing it to exit. This is likely to cause a new process to be used
>   for the next request to your application. (Error code 204)

When the error occurs, none of my php syslog items are output so I can't tell if it's occurring in the same place in my code each time.

It's a job that runs every half hour, so for the most part it works fine.

Any ideas on how to figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you see a corresponding GAE request log entry in the stackdriver logging?

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for your response.  That is the error I'm seeing in the GAE request log.  It doesn't give me much else.  I have been advised that this is an internal error and have raised an issue which they are looking at.  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38058931

Comment: I saw this one before, donno if related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414358/app-engine-im-seeing-500-status-and-204-error-code